# My wine is gone!

Tags: wine

I am on ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bits
I was trying to Install an older stand alone version of flash player so i searched forums and someone suggested i ran this command..

```
~$ sudo apt-get install libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
```

Then i searched elsewhere and i relaized that 32 bit libs are no good for 64 bits system so what i did was to  run this command ...

```
~$ sudo apt-get remove libgtk2.0-0:i386 libnss3-1d:i386 libnspr4-0d:i386 lib32nss-mdns libxml2:i386 libxslt1.1:i386
```

Sad thing is after i done that not only i lost my Skype but my wine is gone too and now that i'm trying to install wine from software centre after i click on install first software centre gets unresponding and so slow and a a message pops up saying downloading packages from nontrusted sources and such...
However i somehow fixed that but now some of my apps are misbeaving. 
My question is how do i restore my system to what it was before i added those lib files? 
Thank you

Comment: Install them again?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Unity, in a terminal run:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && sudo add-apt-repository ppa:wine/wine-builds && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install --install-recommends winehq-staging ubuntu-minimal ubuntu-standard ubuntu-desktop
```